# Use alternating series test to determine convergence/divergence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm positive this series converges, but I just wanted to double check: $$\sum_{n}\frac{(-1)^n}{4n^5 +7}$$

Comment: Check to see if the hypotheses of the alternating series test are met. If so, it converges.

Comment: Does $a_n=\frac{1}{4n^5+7}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$? If so, and since the terms are all positive and sequence is decreasing(?), then by the alternating series test $\sum(-1)^n a_n\quad$...

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{4n^5 + 7} $. Notice

$$ |a_n| = \frac{1}{4n^5 + 7} < \frac{1}{n^5} $$

and since $\sum \frac{1}{n^5} $ convergers (p-series), then by the comparison theorem, we have that desired result.

Comment: >Use alternating series test to determine convergence/divergence, although fair enough that you're providing confirmation of convergence by another test.

Comment: Well done, @Lemur. Perhaps you should add that absolute convergence ==> convergence. +1

Comment: Gracias Don!! Si quieres $50$ puntos, me puedes ayudar con una pregunta que la he puesto en bounty acerca de Jordan Measurable set? Si es que tienes tiempo. :)